# wearApp configuration resolves to more than one apk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, wear-os

I just setup my project add support wearables. I added this line to my dependencies in my build.gradle:

```
wearApp project(':MyWearModule')
```

That is like explained in the documentation ([Packaging Wearable Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html)), but now I get this error:

> Error: Cause: wearApp configuration resolves to more than one apk.

I have some buildTypes but no favoirs, any idea what causes that error?

Comment: Might help if you post your project structure and build.gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why that happend possible a bug in Android Studio 8.0.0, but the solution seems to be to change the used plugin of that wearable module.

I used this statement in my wearable gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Which I replaced by:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

And now the app does compile again.

In my main project I also used the `'android'` plugin instead of `'com.android.application'` after I changed that everythings works now like expected.

Answer (score 0):

try wearApp project(':wear') instead

Comment: Nope: *Error:(123, 0) Project with path ':wear' could not be found in project ':MyProject'.*